# FileCount on Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to find the number of files in a directory. I am using the ls command. Based on the Number of Files, I need to display the count and a message. Script doesn't provide the desired output. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILECOUNT = $(ls /opt/report/ | grep *.ZIP_30 | wc -l);

if [ $FILECOUNT -gt "0" ]; then
      echo "Statistic.filecount: $FILECOUNT";
      echo "Message.filecount: Normal";
else
      echo "Statistic.filecount: $FILECOUNT";
      echo "Message.filecount: Warning";
fi;

exit 0;
```

Comment: You don't need to quote literals, but you do (usually) need to quote variables.  The line `if [ $FILECOUNT -gt "0" ]` is exactly backwards, and should be `if [ "$FILECOUNT" -gt 0 ]`. The quotes aroud the `0` are okay, but the missing quotes around `$FILECOUNT` are a potential problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to make it work with the suggested changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

No spaces allowed around `=` in shell, so:

```
filecount=$(grep -c ZIP_30 /opt/report/*)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a general advise not to parse the result of `ls`, therefore I would advise you the following command:

```
find /opt/report/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.ZIP_30" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax error around `=` that [Gilles pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72265639/4957508) and the quoting issue that [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) commented on, there's a simpler way to count the number of files: use the shell!

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
set -- /opt/report/*.ZIP_30
filecount=$#
if [ "$filecount" -gt 0 ]; then
      echo "Statistic.filecount: $filecount";
      echo "Message.filecount: Normal";
else
      echo "Statistic.filecount: $filecount";
      echo "Message.filecount: Warning";
fi;

exit 0;
```

The basic idea is to use the shell's globbing (wildcard) expansion feature to set the positional parameters to the list of matching files. I've used a bash shell feature (nullglob) for the case where there are exactly no matching files. Normally, the shell would leave the `/opt/report/*.ZIP_30` text as the result of the empty match, but we're trying to count the files, so we want that to disappear when there aren't any matching files. The `$#` variable picks up the number of positional parameters, which gives us the file count. I've also lowercased the shell variable number, just as a good habit to prevent clobbering built-in shell variable names.